# Prove $A\subset\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$

Tags: measure-theory

> **Claim**: Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a non-empty class of sets. Show that for each set $A$ in the $\sigma-\text{ring}$ generated by $\mathscr{C}$, there exists a sequence ${A}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $\mathscr{C}$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$.

I understand that $\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\subset\sigma-\text{ring}$.
But I have no idea on how to prove the claim.

**Question:**

How should I prove the claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Denote by $\mathcal{R}(\mathscr{C})$ the $\sigma$-ring generated by $\mathscr{C}$. Show that

$$\mathcal{D} := \left\{A \in \mathcal{R}(\mathscr{C}); \exists (A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathscr{C}: A \subseteq \bigcup_i A_i \right\}$$

is a $\sigma$-ring. Use $\mathscr{C} \subseteq \mathcal{D}$ to conclude that $\mathcal{R}(\mathscr{C}) \subseteq \mathcal{D}$.